# Where do my apps go when I run out of screen space?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

Didn't realize I had ran out of home screen space on my iPad and I purchased a new app. The App store shows it is installed, and if I search for it I can find it, but I cannot find it on any of my screens.

I've since deleted some other apps and consolidated some into folders, so there is space, but I still cannot find it to place it.

1st Generation iPad
iOS version 5.1.1

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried swiping from right towards the left? Usually it adds screens for newly installed apps when the farthest right screen is full of apps. I have probably 3 screens on my iPad plus a variety of folders.

Comment: @bassplayer7 There is a limit for how many screens you can have. Looks like 11 is the max.

Comment: Ah. OK. I didn't understand clearly the question, and perhaps should have clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad can contain up to 11 pages on its home screen, each page containing up to 20 apps (not counting folders). If all the spots are full when a new app is downloaded, the app will download and install, but not have a spot on the home screen. You can run it through search, the fast app switcher, etc., but not from the home screen.

If space is cleared on the home screen, it appears Apps don't fill in automatically. Rebooting has been known to help.

Now that folders allow more than the 220 apps, I'd recoommend making sure you have an empty spot for the app to appear before purchasing.

Comment: Glaad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, it would appear rebooting caused them to appear. I thought I had tried that, but I guess not.